# $G×G$ and $H×H$ being isomorphic implies $G $ and $H $ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is an exercise from Hungerford chapter 2 section 3. Here $G $ is said to satisfy the ACC and DCC. Then how should I apply the Krull Schmidt theorem to prove the proposition in the title? I tried to show that $G×G $ itself satisfies the ACC and DCC but to no avail. Could anyone help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122839/when-are-two-direct-products-of-groups-isomorphic

Comment: No it is different. I solved the case shown in the link.

Comment: Hey, sorry. I meant to link this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779798/g-times-g-cong-h-times-h-longrightarrow-g-cong-h-for-g-acc-and-dcc?rq=1